# Why does my rails command always create a new application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Forgive me as I'm new to both *nix and ruby on rails.  My rails command always creates a new application and I can't figure out why.  Running "rails new myApp" will just generate a new rails application named "new" in the current directory.  Likewise "rails server" just creates a new application in a folder named "server".  Any ideas?  I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and rails 3.0.9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create your application with `rails new myApp`, there should be a `myApp/script` directory and in there will be a script named `rails`, this is the `rails` that understands `server` and `console`. So, do this:

```
$ rails new MyApp
$ cd MyApp
$ script/rails server
```

To create and start up your application. The naming is a little confusing.

Comment: @user359796: And if you use Rails 2, there will be several scripts (`server`, `console`, ...) in the `scripts/` directory instead of just `rails`.

Comment: This doesn't add up.  If `rails new myApp` created a new Rails application named `new`, then the OP is on Rails 2, *not* Rails 3.

Comment: @David: Sounds to me like he has PATH confusion on top of everything else but maybe he figured out that part on his own. That's why I added the comment about Rails 2. Your point is a good one though.

Comment: This was very common for rails 3 users following rails 2 instructions.  Getting a new app called 'new' is exactly the result of the mix-up due to the syntax change.

Answer (score 25):

For creating project in current directory, you can run:

```
rails new .
```

Answer (score 9):

You have installed rails through apt-get so you have rails 2.
If you want rails 3, use

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge rails # very important so that the new rails is called
sudo apt-get install rubygems
sudo gem install rails
```

Don't forget to relaunch your terminal and you're done.

Comment: thanks, I'm new to using RoR in linux, so the step-by-step definitely helped!

Answer (score 3):

That sounds like the behavior of Rails 2, not Rails 3.  With Rails 2, typing `rails appname` would create a new Rails application named `appname`.  With Rails 3, the syntax is now `rails new appname`.  You should double-check that you're using the version of Rails that you think you are.  To do that, type `rails --version`.

Answer (score 2):

The common way to create a Rails application is:

> rails new MyApp

This will create a folder with your new Rails application called MyApp

If your folder name is the same name you plan to use for your application you can use the command below:

> rails new .

Notice the period at the end telling it to use the current directory.

If you want to supply a specific application name, you’ll have to do the following:

> rails new  /path/to/folder/you/want/to/use

Answer (score 1):

Rails 2.3.5

```
rails new       # will create a project new 
rails new myapp # still will create a project new
rails server    # will create a project server
```

to run the server : 
`cd script` ( a directory in your project folder ) and then run `./server`